# Order of field retrieval alters data

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, asp-classic

Have one here that literally has me pulling my hair out:

If I use the following code:

```
SQL = "SELECT * from Incident WHERE"
SQL = SQL & " active=1 ORDER BY incidentdate"
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof
    idate = FormatDateTime(Recordset("incidentdate"),vbShortDate)
    inumber = Recordset("incidentnum")

    Response.Write inumber & "<br />" & vbCrLf
    Response.Write idate & vbCrLf
    Recordset.MoveNext     

Loop
```

I get the following output:

```
2015-U1-FO-001
01/17/2015
```

If I switch the lines right after the `Do While...` line so my code reads as such:

```
SQL = "SELECT * from Incident WHERE"
SQL = SQL & " active=1 ORDER BY incidentdate"
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof
    inumber = Recordset("incidentnum")
    idate = FormatDateTime(Recordset("incidentdate"),vbShortDate)

    Response.Write inumber & "<br />" & vbCrLf
    Response.Write idate & vbCrLf
    Recordset.MoveNext     

Loop
```

My output changes to:

```
2015-U1-FO-001
12/30/1899
```

It seems to cause the `Recordset("incidentdate")` to return an empty string.

Any ideas on what I am overlooking?

Comment: Is Incident a view? Is there a CASE (or COALESCE/ISNULL) for IncidentDate? I've seen similar edge cases crop up in SQL Server based on execution plan...though I'm not sure why execution plan would change for these two scenarios.

Comment: Could do with more detail, is `Incident` a table or a view, could you post the view schema?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe anything of the above.

1. A cursor may restrict movement, writability, and visibility of changes, but never whether you can read the the fields of the current record or not (in any order).
2. The .Fields collection can be indexed by number **or** name. In the second case the (possible) order of fieldnames in the SELECT statement doesn't matter.

Evidence:

```
Option Explicit

Dim sCS : sCS     = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=...;Password=...;Initial Catalog=Trials;Data Source=WINXPSP3\SQLEXPRESS;"
Dim oDb : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oDb.Open sCS
Dim oRs : Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRs.Open "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Alpha]", oDb
WScript.Echo oRs.CursorType, "adOpenForwardOnly 0 Default. Uses a forward-only cursor"
WScript.Echo oRs.GetString(2, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "<Null>")
oRs.Close
WScript.Echo "-----------"
oRs.Open "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Alpha]", oDb
WScript.Echo oRs("StartDate")
WScript.Echo oRs("Id")
oRs.Close
WScript.Echo "-----------"
oRs.Open "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Alpha]", oDb
WScript.Echo oRs("Id")
WScript.Echo oRs("StartDate")
oRs.Close
WScript.Echo "-----------"
oRs.Open "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [Alpha]", oDb
WScript.Echo oRs("StartDate")
WScript.Echo oRs("Id")
WScript.Echo oRs("Id")
WScript.Echo oRs("StartDate")
oRs.MoveNext
WScript.Echo "..........."
WScript.Echo oRs("StartDate")
WScript.Echo oRs("Id")
oRs.MoveNext
WScript.Echo "..........."
WScript.Echo oRs("Id")
WScript.Echo oRs("StartDate")
oRs.Close
oDb.Close
```

Output:

```
cscript 28054592.vbs
0 adOpenForwardOnly 0 Default. Uses a forward-only cursor
209     10.06.2002      11.02.2003      2090
418     28.04.2000      10.06.2000      4180
627     03.09.2000      01.11.2000      6270

-----------
10.06.2002
209
-----------
209
10.06.2002
-----------
10.06.2002
209
209
10.06.2002
...........
28.04.2000
418
...........
627
03.09.2000
```

Comment: I'm of the same opinion if i'm honest.